# How to change the directory during runtime and store the file in different location

Tags: python, file, directory, filepath, file-handling

Let's assume I am writing Student details as a list into a CSV file.
Currently, I am working in a directory:

```
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Pythontraining
```

but I want to store those CSV file in `"StudentDetails"` folder which is present in:

```
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/StudentDetails
```

as well as

```
/home/ubuntu/Documents/StudentDetails
```

I want to store the CSV file in both the directory during runtime. I am creating a new file (outfile), but I want to store it in a different directory. Say, I need to store the "outfile" into the folder whose name is "StudentDetails". In my case, I have created the "StudentDetails" folder in two different directory.

I want to save the file (outfile) in both directories. How should I do it manually?

```
try:
 f=open(outfile, 'w')
 for j in m:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(j)
except OSError:
 print "Can't Change the current directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to save the same file in two different directories, and to do it in a convenient way. 
There are at least two ways:

1. You can create a function, that will save your desired data into two different files in a loop. And we need a function in order to have our code readable:

   ```
   def multiple_save_st_details(m, path1, path2):
       for outfile in [path1, path2]:
           try:
               f=open(outfile, 'w')
               for j in m:
                   writer = csv.writer(f)
                   writer.writerow(j)
           except OSError as o:
               print("Can't Change the current directory")
   ```
2. We have a file to the first location and then copy it to a different directory:

   ```
   def save_w_copy_st_details(m, filepath1, path2):
       try:
           f=open(filepath1, 'w')
           for j in m:
               writer = csv.writer(f)
               writer.writerow(j)
       except OSError as o:
           print("Can't Change the current directory")
       import shutil
       shutil.copy2(filepath1, path2)
   ```

In that case, the filename for the target path may be excluded and will be taken the same as in the source